# How to set radom text on Buttons which are created dynamically in android?

Tags: android, button

First of all sorry for poor english, here i attached screen shot, i created dynamic buttons of first row, and buttons of seconds row are statically from xml, and i can create buttons successfully and now (1) i want when i click on any buttons of below row that time i want set text on first first button which is dynamically created, and in my code it is set on last button, (2) if first button has some text than text will set to second button, i am using below code.

```
private Button Dynamic_Button;

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Dynamic_Button = new Button(this);
        Dynamic_Button.setId(i);

        final int id_ = Dynamic_Button.getId();
        layout.addView(Dynamic_Button, params);
        Dynamic_Button = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
        Dynamic_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                        "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        });
    }
```

// and below code for set text on dynamic button

```
Dynamic_Button.setText(str);
```

[image]

Comment: where you declared `Dynamic_Button`?

Comment: @ling.s i declared variable for Dynamic_Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code - tried and tested

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button dynamic_Button;
private LinearLayout layout = null;
private Button add = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dynamic_Button = new Button(this);
        dynamic_Button.setId(i);
        final int id_ = dynamic_Button.getId();
        layout.addView(dynamic_Button, params);
        dynamic_Button = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
        dynamic_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                        "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        });
    }

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if(((Button)findViewById(i)).getText().toString().trim().length()<=0)
                {
                    ((Button)findViewById(i)).setText(""+i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rel_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_tags"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_static_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_tags" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1st of all you used `length()<=0` what kind of a condition was that ?, 2nd read the users 2nd point in his question `if first button has some text than text will set to second button` and 3rd the user has already specified `Dynamic_Button.setText(str); ` so input is `String` but in your case its numbers so -1 for this answer

Answer (score 1):

Save it in a collection, an `ArrayList` for instance, and retrieve the object at the correct index when you press on the `Button`

Answer (score 1):

It is set on the last button because of the for loop that your using

You have to create an array of buttons instead of using just one Button Object

try this
Create a class variable

```
Button[] Dynamic_Button = new Button[5];

layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Dynamic_Button[i-1] = new Button(this);
        Dynamic_Button[i-1].setId(i);

        final int id_ = Dynamic_Button[i-1].getId();
        layout.addView(Dynamic_Button[i-1], params);
        //This is not necessary
        //Dynamic_Button[i-1] = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
        Dynamic_Button[i-1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                        "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        });
    }
```

and in your `settext` use this logic

```
public void setTextToDynamicButton(String text){
    for (int i = Dynamic_Button.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if(i-1 >= 0){
        Dynamic_Button[i].setText(Dynamic_Button[i-1].getText().toString());
        }
    }
    Dynamic_Button[0].setText(text);
}
```

Comment: @user406090 have made some small changes pls check it

Comment: Index out of bound error when buttons create dynamically

Comment: I would suggest to log the problem, but I think you have solved it anyway